# Fatal error: Uncaught Twig\Error\LoaderError

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I have just deployed my application on the server. If I use `APP_ENV=dev`, everything works fine but if I use `APP_ENV=prod`, I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Twig\Error\LoaderError: The
>   "/home/httpd/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/api_tapalle\vendor\symfony\framework-bundle/Resources/views"
>   directory does not exist
>   ("/home/httpd/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/api_tapalle\vendor\symfony\framework-bundle/Resources/views").
>   in
>   /home/httpd/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/api_tapalle/vendor/twig/twig/src/Loader/FilesystemLoader.php:106
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/httpd/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/api_tapalle/var/cache/prod/ContainerTP5linE/srcApp_KernelProdContainer.php(471):
>   Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader->addPath('/home/httpd/vho...',
>   'Framework') #1
>   /home/httpd/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/api_tapalle/var/cache/prod/ContainerTP5linE/srcApp_KernelProdContainer.php(729):
>   ContainerTP5linE\srcApp_KernelProdContainer->getTwigService() #2
>   /home/httpd/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/api_tapalle/var/cache/prod/ContainerTP5linE/srcApp_KernelProdContainer.php(346):
>   ContainerTP5linE\srcApp_KernelProdContainer->getSensioFrameworkExtra_View_ListenerService() #3 /home/httpd/vhosts/y in /home/httpd/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/api_tapalle/vendor/twig/twig/src/Loader/FilesystemLoader.php
>   on line 106

Since I have this error, I have used `php bin/console cache:clear -e prod` to clear the cache and then uploaded *var* and *vendor* directories again.

The weird thing is that *vendor\symfony\framework-bundle/Resources/views* and *vendor/twig/twig/src/Loader/FilesystemLoader.php* exist on the server!

Why do I get this error?

Comment: Maybe you have a problem in htaccess file.

Comment: Don't know why but you seem to have both slash and backslash in your file url : "/home/httpd/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/api_tapalle\vendor\symfony\framework-bundle/Resources/views"

Answer (score 0):

updlas the project with all the cache production, dont make a cache clear

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).